# Indefinite equation as the index of a Sigma notation?

Tags: summation, notation

Let $t_1$, $t_2$ and $n$ be nonnegative positive integers.

$$\sum_{t_1+2t_2=n} 1. \tag1$$

How does $t_1+2t_2=n$ dictate the behaviour of the sum?

I understand that

$$\sum^k_{n} 1 = k.$$

For (1), does it mean that for a number $n$, let the number of solutions to the indefinite equation, $t_1+2t_2=n$ be $k$,

$$\sum_{t_1+2t_2=n} 1 = k.$$

Is the above statement true?

For more context, I had (1) appear in the following:

$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}\left(\sum_{t_1+2t_2=n}1\right)x^n = \sum^\infty_{t_1=0}\sum^\infty_{t_2=0}x^{t_1+t_2}.\tag2$$

How can (2) be interpreted?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take $n=11$ as an example. We have
$$11+2\cdot0 = 9+2\cdot1 = 7+2\cdot2 = 5+2\cdot3 = 3+2\cdot4 = 1+2\cdot5.$$
Therefore, assuming $t_1,t_2\geq0$,
$$
\sum_{t_1+2t_2=11} f(t_1,t_2) = f(11,0) + f(9,1) + f(7,2) + f(5,3) + f(3,4) + f(1,5).
$$
With $f(t_1,t_2)=1$ (constant function) we thus get
$$
\sum_{t_1+2t_2=11} 1 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 6.
$$